# Class and their responsibility analysis

Tags: class, responsibility

Suppose i have a use case "Customer Deposits Money on Account". Where should the functionality "Deposit()" go ? Customer or Account?. What should be the design for this use case ?

Comment: Each customer can have an account associated with it.  Depositing is an action taken by the customer, so this function/method should go there I think.

Comment: I have one customer multiple accounts scenario. So i plan to design like this:
Class Customer{
IList<IAccount> accountList;
deposit(IAccount account,amount)
{
 //validate if account exists in accountlist here
account.deposit(amount);
} 

is this ok ?

Answer (score 1):

When a `deposit` action is performed then this action records atleast the `deposit_amount` and `deposit_date` on which the action was done. So, placement of this action `deposit` depends upon the following four scenarios (or relation between `customer` and `account`):

[1] An `account` can belong to many `customer`. However, a `customer` can have a single `account`. That is, the relation is one-to-many from `account` to `customer`. In such a case, `deposit` (`deposit_amount` and `deposit_date`) action should be part of `customer`.

[2] A `customer` can hold many `account`. However, an `account` can belong to single `customer`. That is, the relation is one-to-many from `customer` to `account`. In such a case, `deposit` (`deposit_amount` and `deposit_date`) action should be part of `account`.

[3] Many `account` can belong to a single `customer`. Also, an `account` can be hold by many `customer`. That is, the relation is many-to-many from `account` to `customer`. In such a case, it will be better to have a separate class `CDeposit{`customer_id, account_id, deposit_amount, deposit_date}`which will record this action`deposit`.

[4] An `account` can belong to only one `customer`. Also a `customer` can hold only one `account`. That is, the relation is one-to-one from `account` to `customer`. In such a case, `deposit` (`deposit_amount` and `deposit_date`) action can be part of any of `account` or `customer`.